# WPF Wait Cursor With BackgroundWorker Thread

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, mouse-cursor

I want to show the hourglass cursor and disable the window while a BackgroundWorker process runs in another thread.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(...)
    Dim box As New AnotherWpfWindow()
    box.Owner = Me
    ...
    box.ShowDialog()
    If (box.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault = True) Then
        Me.IsEnabled = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Wait
        MyBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(...)
    UpdateInterface()
    Me.IsEnabled = True
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub
```

The window becomes disabled like I want, but the cursor remains an arrow.  How can I make it the Wait cursor?

It seems to work for [vg1890](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31221/vg1890) according to this question:  [Disabling all but one control in a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273809/disabling-all-but-one-control-in-a-wpf-window)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What seems to be happening here is that WPF is ignoring the Cursor setting on the disabled window.  The following workaround seems to work: instead of disabling the window itself, disable the *content* of the window:

C#:

```
((UIElement)Content).IsEnabled = false;
Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

// and in RunWorkerCompleted handler:
((UIElement)Content).IsEnabled = true;
Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Visual Basic:

```
DirectCast(Content, UIElement).IsEnabled = False
Cursor = Cursors.Wait

' and in RunWorkerCompleted handler:'
DirectCast(Content, UIElement).IsEnabled = True
Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to change the cursor globally, is..

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

//Do something
//...

Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```