# How to Disabling all button but one in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, button

in my xaml file i have 5 buttons i want to disable all except one

how i can do this

note : my Buttons in three StackPanels so i can't use this answer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273809/disabling-all-but-one-child-control-in-a-wpf-window)

this code give me compile error

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    ctrl.Enabled = false;

CancelButton.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Bind the Enable to match a specific enumeration

Comment: Does this have to be in code-behind or can it be in xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more info perhaps?
One way of doing is to bind IsEnabled property of all buttons that you want to control, to a public property in the "code behind", and then set its value when needed.

```
IsEnabled={Binding Path=IsEnabledProperty}
```

Something like that, I can't be more specific at the moment, cos I'm not on my work computer, but I'm sure someone will come up with a propper example ;)